# How to get accelerated using multiprocessing/process_map et al., with heavy calculation in python (e.g., numpy)?

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing, tqdm

I've got a function written in Numpy where each call costs about 2 seconds, but I have to run it tens of thousands of times. It is obvious that I should use multi-thread or multi-processing, and the easiest way might be using `process_map` or `thread_map` in `tqdm.contrib.concurrent`. But I found it not working as expected.

Here is an example that I've tested:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from tqdm.auto import tqdm
from tqdm.contrib.concurrent import process_map, thread_map


def mydataset(size, length):
    for ii in range(length):
        yield np.random.rand(*size)


def calc(mat):
    # simulate some heavy calculation
    for ii in range(1000):
        avg = np.mean(mat)
        std = np.std(mat)
    return avg, std

def main():
    ds = list(mydataset((500,500), 100))

    t0 = time.time()
    res1 = []
    for mat in tqdm(ds):
        res1.append(calc(mat))
    print(f'for loop: {time.time() - t0}s')

    t0 = time.time()
    res2 = list(map(calc, tqdm(ds)))
    print(f'native map: {time.time() - t0}s')

    t0 = time.time()
    res3 = process_map(calc, ds)
    print(f'process map: {time.time() - t0}s')

    t0 = time.time()
    res4 = thread_map(calc, ds)
    print(f'thread map: {time.time() - t0}s')

    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And it came out:

```
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:51<00:00,  1.93it/s]
for loop: 51.884708642959595s
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:52<00:00,  1.91it/s]
native map: 52.48910164833069s
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [01:10<00:00,  1.41it/s]
process map: 71.0565574169159s
100%|████████████████████████████████████████████| 100/100 [00:41<00:00,  2.39it/s]
thread map: 42.04276633262634s
```

`process_map` is much slower than a for-loop, and `thread_map` also costs too much time, considering there are 28 cores in my PC. Yes, the CPU usage is not as high as expected, only 1 to 2 cores are at 100%.

And it seems that when my `calc` do something simpler, `process_map` DO have acceleration.

My test environment is `openSUSE Tumbleweed with Linux 6.63`, `python 3.10.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2023, 20:08:06) [GCC 11.3.0]`, `tqdm 4.66.1`.

I also tried the previous code under `windows 11 x64` with `python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]`, `tqdm 4.62.3`, the result are similar, CPU usage reached 100% (all cores) in taskmgr, but `process_map` (64.32s) and `thread_map` (66.13s) are slightly faster than for-loop (78.41s) and map (79.79s).

So my question is, **what is the correct way to do multi-processing/multi-threading acceleration where there are heavy calculations?** How could I speed-up those calculations without manually splitting the dataset and running several for-loops concurrently?

Comment: I'm able to get a significant speedup in process_map on your example by using a smaller dtype, by putting `ds = [mat.astype('float32') for mat in ds]` after the line which creates the dataset. That suggests that this benchmark is mostly held back by inter-process communication costs. Don't know if that solution is applicable to your other problem.

Comment: the main problem here is that this data is bigger than the L3 cache, so you can assume every read/write is happening directly to the RAM, the code is bottlenecked by the RAM bandwidth ..... so ..... buy more RAM sticks and populate more channels, normal computers have 2-3 channels and workstations have 3-6 channels, and servers have up to 12 channels and sometimes more, or push work to GPU, any GPU within the last 10 years can chew through those calculations with no problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code and achieved a time of 64 seconds when using it as it is (4 cores). Afterwards I increased the core count to 6 and 8, but only got a very small gain. So it's not limited by the calculation itself, but by the copying of the matrices.

So I changed your code, using a manager to hold your data. That copies the matrices only once, at the beginning of the calculation. I ran the loop and obtained a time of 2 seconds. Which means, avoiding to copy the data makes it much faster. The only things that are copied are the reference to the manager and some integer-numbers for the tasks.

here is my code:

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing import Pool, Manager


def mydataset(size, length):
    for ii in range(length):
        yield np.random.rand(*size)


def calc(idx, mat_list):
    # simulate some heavy calculation
    for ii in range(1000):
        avg = np.mean(mat_list[idx])
        std = np.std(mat_list[idx])
    return avg, std


def main():
    ds = list(mydataset((500, 500), 100))

    mypool = Pool(4)
    manager = Manager()
    mylist = manager.list(ds)

    t0 = time.time()
    res1 = mypool.starmap(calc, zip(range(len(ds)), mylist))
    print(f"map manager: {time.time() - t0}s")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
map manager: 1.935054063796997s
```

So, try to avoid extensive copy-operation during your multiprocessing as they usually bottleneck the operation. If you have lots of data, use a sharing-concept where the data is copied only once and later read from that source.

Comment: where does this copying happen in the OP code

Comment: for example in the process_map. The contains of `ds` need to be copied to the separate process to be accessible there. It seems that this takes more time than the actual calculation.

Comment: if copying is the problem then `thread_map` should be as fast as your version

Comment: Wouldn't this give a problem with the GIL in Windows? IMHO spawning a new process copies the whole memory into a new process. `process_map` executes the `calc` functions and sequentially copies the matrices into the `calc`-execution. Does Windows spawn new threads, sharing the memory?